# iText: writing a text in which every character is surrounded by a square

Tags: java, itext

I have a tab:

```
    PdfPTable tab2 = new PdfPTable(2);
```

with 2 columns. I want write a text inside this table (eg: hello) where every character is inside a single square (Spaced from each other of few mm).
At the moment I'm trying to do this, with an image with 12 (max word size) squares. I want to loop through the word, and write with the absolute position every character in every square.
I'm using:

```
    float t2height = tab2.getTotalHeight();
```

But I've some problem to find the right position, because the pdf size is not fixed and there're others tabs.

I tried too to make a pdf Cell for every character, but doesn't work good (I don't know how to set the correct width and how insert little spaces between the squares). For example here I'm trying to write RH with R in the first squre and H in the second:

```
    PdfPCell cellUser = new PdfPCell();
    PdfPCell cellUser2 = new PdfPCell();
    PdfPTable tabUs = new  PdfPTable(new float[]{1});
    Paragraph pUtente = new Paragraph("R",fontTesto14);
    Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("H",fontTesto14);
    cellUser.addElement(pUtente);
    cellUser2.addElement(p2);
    tabUs.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    tab2.addCell(nomeUtenteAssegnato);
    tabUs.addCell(cellUser);
    tabUs.addCell(cellUser2);
    tabUs.setWidths(new int[]{1});//I tried with other sizes, but nothing happened
    tab2.addCell(tabUs);
```

So, there's a simple way to do this? For example find the absolute position of the image or something built-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in a unconventionally way: I used the: *getTotalHeight()* to the previous *PdfPTable* element, and after several tries I found the right position. After I write the text in the absolute position, using *setCharacterSpacing(characterSpacing)* because my squares was a little spaced.
But this don't work good, because some character like I and l, have a lesser size then W or others. So I loop every character and I write each in an absolute position.